# Tabu package row space option

Tags: tabu

If we given line space `\\[1pt]` in the particular row which takes extra more space using "`tabu`"

We know that `tabu` package non maintained, I just check whether is there any other option to controlling
more vertical space when I given "`\\[1pt]`"

Note: `tabulinesep` is one of solution but it takes extra space for all the rows.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

Working capital management deals with the management of current assets — cash, accounts receivable and inventory — and their financing. Good working capital management is always important for companies. \begin{table}[h!]
{\begin{tabu}{p{100pt}p{100pt}}
Nikole Gyles
&
BCom (Hons) UTas, CA, CPA\\
\tabucline{-}
Janice Loftus
&
BBus NSWIT, MCom (Hons) UNSW, FCPA\\
Carmen Ridley&BSc (Hons) Mathematics, FCA\\
\tabucline{-}
BEc, GradDipCom, MCom (Hons), PhD Monash
&
BEc, GradDipCom, MCom (Hons), PhD Monash University, CPA, CA\\
\end{tabu}}
{}
\end{table}
Working capital management deals with the management of current assets — cash, accounts receivable and inventory — and their financing. Good working capital management is always important for companies.

\begin{table}[h!]
{\begin{tabu}{p{100pt}p{100pt}}
Nikole Gyles
&
BCom (Hons) UTas, CA, CPA\\
\tabucline{-}
Janice Loftus
&
BBus NSWIT, MCom (Hons) UNSW, FCPA\\
Carmen Ridley&BSc (Hons) Mathematics, FCA\\[1pt]
\tabucline{-}
BEc, GradDipCom, MCom (Hons), PhD Monash
&
BEc, GradDipCom, MCom (Hons), PhD Monash University, CPA, CA\\
\end{tabu}}
{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tabu` package is not advisable to use...

Comment: In your current example, you don't even use the flexible width columns from `tabu`. So why not go for a simple `tabular` instead and use the horizontal lines from `booktabs`?

Comment: I get no additional space with your example in a current tex system.

Answer (score 1):

To long for comment ...

After removing all unnecessary curly braces your MWE gives:

[image]

As mentioned in above comments, it is not advisable to use `tabu`. It is buggy and not maintained. After last revision of `array` package, on which it is heavily dependent, it has additional problems. Rather use standard `tabular` or other table environments.

**Edit:**
The same result is obtained by use of the standard  `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Working capital management deals with the management of current assets —
cash, accounts receivable and inventory — and their financing. Good working
capital management is always important for companies. 
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{p{100pt}p{100pt}}
Nikole Gyles
&
BCom (Hons) UTas, CA, CPA\\
\hline
Janice Loftus
&
BBus NSWIT, MCom (Hons) UNSW, FCPA\\
Carmen Ridley&BSc (Hons) Mathematics, FCA\\
\\hline
BEc, GradDipCom, MCom (Hons), PhD Monash
&
BEc, GradDipCom, MCom (Hons), PhD Monash University, CPA, CA\\
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
Working capital management deals with the management of current assets —
cash, accounts receivable and inventory — and their financing. Good working
capital management is always important for companies.

    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{p{100pt}p{100pt}}
Nikole Gyles
&
BCom (Hons) UTas, CA, CPA\\
\hline
Janice Loftus
&
BBus NSWIT, MCom (Hons) UNSW, FCPA\\
Carmen Ridley&BSc (Hons) Mathematics, FCA\\[1pt]
\hline
BEc, GradDipCom, MCom (Hons), PhD Monash
&
BEc, GradDipCom, MCom (Hons), PhD Monash University, CPA, CA\\
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (2):**
with use of `center` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Working capital management deals with the management of current assets —
cash, accounts receivable and inventory — and their financing. Good working
capital management is always important for companies. 
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{100pt}p{100pt}}
Nikole Gyles
&
BCom (Hons) UTas, CA, CPA\\
\hline
Janice Loftus
&
BBus NSWIT, MCom (Hons) UNSW, FCPA\\
Carmen Ridley&BSc (Hons) Mathematics, FCA\\
\\hline
BEc, GradDipCom, MCom (Hons), PhD Monash
&
BEc, GradDipCom, MCom (Hons), PhD Monash University, CPA, CA\\
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
Working capital management deals with the management of current assets —
cash, accounts receivable and inventory — and their financing. Good working
capital management is always important for companies.

    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{100pt}p{100pt}}
Nikole Gyles
&
BCom (Hons) UTas, CA, CPA\\
\hline
Janice Loftus
&
BBus NSWIT, MCom (Hons) UNSW, FCPA\\
Carmen Ridley&BSc (Hons) Mathematics, FCA\\[1pt]
\hline
BEc, GradDipCom, MCom (Hons), PhD Monash
&
BEc, GradDipCom, MCom (Hons), PhD Monash University, CPA, CA\\
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After removing "{" and "}" before and after \begin{tabu} and \end{tabu}, still the same space retained as per attachment. Is any other modification required?